# Calling an img tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, textarea

I am new at javascript and have been researching this for hours and can't seem to find an answer I understand. What I'm trying to do is once an image is clicked on the webpage I would like the textarea on my html to change fonts. Thanks for the help in advanced :)

Here is my HTML

```
 <div id="buttonWrapper">       <!--BUTTON WRAPPER START -->
                <div id="button01">
                    <img id="buttonImage" src="imges/font01.png" alt="button01"> </span>
                    </div>

<div id="textSpot" >
                    <textarea name="word">  </textarea>
                    </div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
    function init(){
    document.querySelectorAll(#buttonImage).onclick = changeFont;



function changeFont(){
    document.querySelectorAll("word").style.fontFamily = "'Oswald', sans-serif";    
}
```

}

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: If I am on the right track with my javascript, if so what am I missing? Or is my javascript fully in the wrong.

Comment: @Hellodueworld Try wrapping `#buttonImage` in quotes and using `textarea[name='word']` instead of `word`.

Comment: `#buttonImage` is not JavaScript, you want `"#buttonImage"`. `querySelectorAll(...)` returns a list; you want `getElementById('buttonImage')`, `querySelector('#buttonImage')` or `querySelectorAll('#buttonImage')[0]`. Also, it is not obvious if you ever actually call the `init` function. EDIT: also what @rioc0719 said about `word` :P

Comment: @rioc0719 unfortunately still not working, damn.

Comment: @Hellodueworld Are you calling `init()` somewhere else in your code? Also, make sure that `function init()` is properly closed. I don't see a matching `}` in the code above.

Comment: @rioc0719 I have window.onload = init;  at the top of my page.

Comment: @Hellodueworld See this fiddle: [Collaborate](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DeqfENni2g)

Comment: Change `document.querySelectorAll("word")` to `document.getElementsByName("word")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this

HTML

```
<div id="buttonWrapper">       
<!--BUTTON WRAPPER START -->
    <div id="button01">
        <img id="buttonImage" src="imges/font01.png" alt="button01"> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="textSpot" >
    <textarea name="word">  </textarea>
</div>
```

Js File

```
function init()
{
   document.getElementById('buttonImage').onclick = changeFont;
}
function changeFont()
{
   var textareas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='word']");
   for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++)
   {
      textareas[0].style.fontFamily = "'Oswald', sans-serif";
   }    
}
```